# Dell Powervault MD3000 - Not sharing Files between servers

Tags: raid, dell-powervault

I'm a developer who has to set up a Dell Powervault MD3000 due to lack of resources.

I have connected the Powervault to 2 Dell 2950 servers via the SAS cables.  I performed the setup using Dell's MD Storage Manager software (4 disks, RAID 5 with hot spare).  Then I added the disks using Windows 2003 disk management (Basic, not dynamic disk and formatted with NTFS).

When I add files to the array from one server, they are not visible on the other server (and vice-versa).

Is the error in the windows disk management configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NTFS isn't a cluster filesystem. If you're really trying to share the same LUNs between two server computers you're going to have problems (at the least). Mounting the same NTFS filesystem on two different systems simultaneously is a recipe for filesystem corruption.

If you really want to do this you'll need a cluster filesystem, like the one packaged with [Veritas Storage Foundation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VERITAS_Storage_Foundation), as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can't share disks directly between machines like this due to each individual machine caching data and file tables unless you are either using clustering or have addition software to enable it.